# Draw centered circle and implement an object (bitmp) that moves along the circle

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a new UI window and drew a circle.  I would like to have a small figure (think small stick figure) move along the perimeter of the circle at a certain rate. The rate of movement is probably easy enough to change. How do I have an object move along the perimeter of the circle?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Drawing Ellipse"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 200
        self.width = 750
        self.height = 750
        self.InitWindow()


    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()



    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter  = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(200,200, 400,400)




App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Two things: 1) only one question per post is allowed, so choose what you want to be answered: *fixing* the drawing, or implementing the animation 2) you are *not* drawing the circle at the center: you are setting the geometry with a width and height of 750, so its center will be at 375x375, but if you create an ellipse at 200x200 with a diameter of 400, the center will be at 400x400. So, you either set a size of 800x800, or you set the origin of the ellipse at center *minus* the radius: 175x175.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are some issues with your code:

1. the circle is not correctly centered: if a *centered* circle positioned at (200, 200) has a 400 diameter, the window should have a width and height equal to 800; but this is not a good choice, as the window could be resized (by the user or the OS), and if you want to ensure that it is actually centered, you need to adapt the rect used for the painting to the current size;
2. no painting should ever happen in a QMainWindow unless absolutely required: a Qt main window uses a *central widget* to show its main contents, and if you want to do any "main" custom painting, it should happen in *that* central widget; there are very few cases for which a `paintEvent` should be implemented in a QMainWindow, but they are very only for specific and very advanced scenarios;
3. a QMainWindow has an internal layout that takes into account possible features such as a menu bar, a status bar, and possibly some amount of toolbars and dock widgets, so you cannot rely on a fixed geometry for the painting, as you risk that the painting would be partially hidden by other objects;
4. existing class properties should never, *ever* be overwritten; I'm specifically referring to `self.width` and `self.height`, which are existing *dynamic* properties of any QWidget subclass, and should never be overwritten; I know that there are some tutorials that use that pattern (I've already warned some bloggers about this), but you should *not* follow those suggestions;

Considering the above, the solution is to create a QWidget subclass, and implement the `paintEvent` of *that* class. Then, using a [QVariantAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) allows to create a smooth animation that can be used to correctly position the moving image on the perimeter.

In the following example I'm using a [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) with a simple ellipse, which allows me to get the position using the [`pointAtPercent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#pointAtPercent) function.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QPen, QPixmap, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPoint, QPointF, QVariantAnimation


class CirclingWidget(QWidget):
    offset = QPoint()
    def __init__(self, diameter=1, relative=True, sprite=None, 
            anglesPerSecond=360, clockwise=True, offset=None, alignment=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.relative = relative
        self.clockwise = clockwise
        self.setSprite(sprite, offset or alignment)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(startValue=0., endValue=1., 
            duration=360000 / anglesPerSecond, loopCount=-1)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.update)

    def setSprite(self, sprite, arg):
        if isinstance(sprite, str):
            sprite = QPixmap(sprite)
        if isinstance(sprite, QPixmap) and not sprite.isNull():
            self.sprite = sprite
            if isinstance(arg, Qt.AlignmentFlag):
                self.setAlignment(arg)
            else:
                self.setOffset(arg)
        else:
            self.sprite = None
        self.update()

    def setAlignment(self, alignment=None):
        if self.sprite:
            x = y = 0
            if alignment is not None:
                if alignment & Qt.AlignHCenter:
                    x = -self.sprite.width() / 2
                elif alignment & Qt.AlignRight:
                    x = -self.sprite.width()
                if alignment & Qt.AlignVCenter:
                    y = -self.sprite.height() / 2
                elif alignment & Qt.AlignBottom:
                    y = -self.sprite.height()
            self.offset = QPointF(x, y)
        self.update()

    def setOffset(self, offset=None):
        if self.sprite:
            x = y = 0
            if isinstance(offset, int):
                x = y = offset
            elif isinstance(offset, float):
                x = self.sprite.width() * offset
                y = self.sprite.height() * offset
            elif isinstance(offset, (QPoint, QPointF)):
                x = offset.x()
                y = offset.y()
            elif isinstance(offset, (tuple, list)):
                x, y = offset
            self.offset = QPointF(x, y)
        self.update()

    def setAnglesPerSecond(self, ratio):
        self.animation.setDuration(360000 / ratio)

    def setClockwise(self, clockwise=True):
        if self.clockwise != clockwise:
            self.clockwise = clockwise
            self.animation.setCurrentTime(
                self.animation.duration() - self.animation.currentTime())
            self.update()

    def start(self, angle=0):
        self.animation.start()
        # the angle is considered clockwise, starting from 12h
        start = (angle - 90) / 360 % 1
        self.animation.setCurrentTime(start * self.animation.duration())
        self.update()

    def stop(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter  = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHints(painter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))

        size = self.diameter
        if self.relative:
            size *= min(self.width(), self.height())

        rect = QRectF(0, 0, size, size)
        rect.moveCenter(QRectF(self.rect()).center())

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(rect)
        painter.drawPath(path)

        if self.sprite:
            pos = self.animation.currentValue()
            if not self.clockwise:
                pos = 1 - pos
            pos = path.pointAtPercent(pos)
            painter.drawPixmap(pos + self.offset, self.sprite)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Drawing Ellipse"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 200
        self._width = 800
        self._height = 800
        self.InitWindow()


    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self._width, self._height)

        self.circleWidget = CirclingWidget(.5, sprite='image.png', 
            anglesPerSecond=60, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.circleWidget)
        self.circleWidget.start(90)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Finally, avoid mixed import styles. The following lines might lead to confusion:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
```

You either import QtGui, or you import the individual classes of that submodule.

Comment: this looks great, however I I don't see the animation moving.  What is it supposed to be?  
 DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  self.animation = QVariantAnimation(startValue=0., endValue=1.,
py:77: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.\self.animation.setCurrentTime(start * self.animation.duration())

Comment: Also. where is the radius of the circle mentioned ?

Comment: @sam 1) Have you added an image file? 2) that's just a warning, but you can fix it by using `int()` for both the values of the `duration` keyword argument and the `setDuration()` function. 3) if you look at the init of the circle, you can set a relative diameter (that is always based on the minimum between height and width) or an absolute one (in pixels).

Comment: I have not added an image file, where can I add one, inside of the which function and line.  Sorry this is just all new to me.  Thanks!

Comment: @sam please read the code: there's a `sprite='image.png'` argument, so you need to have an image named `image.png` in the folder of the script.

Comment: Thanks, yea sorry I missed that..  that works great, thanks so much.  Last question, how would I add a background image on top of the circle but behind the moving object?

Comment: @sam What do you mean for "background image on top of the circle"? Does it mean that you don't want to see the circle?

Comment: yea I dont want to see the circle, the circle is just for reference of the image going around it... sorry for the confusion

Comment: For future reference, always take your time before asking a question. Clarify with yourself what you need to do and what you need to ask: your first post (and its current title) was about drawing a circle and the problems in centering it, then you asked about moving an object on the circle, and now you don't want to draw the circle at all. I suggest you to carefully *study* the documentation about all the functions used in your example and my answer (as they already contain all functions you will need), then try on your own. If you still have problems, create a new post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227053/discussion-between-sam-and-musicamante).